# How to convert HTML to PDF and share the pdf file with expo react native share (ios) with printToFileAsync

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

I can generate the pdfBuffer by sending the HTML to the backend, but receiving the data and sharing it with expo share is where I‘m stuck at. Really Apreciate for any help.

The lib I'm using is

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf')
```

https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf

I have tried the following code and search google for 4 days with no prevail.
frontend react native code

```js
  const createPdf = () => {
    const html = insertHtml(orders)

    axios('http://573f-98-14-177-227.ngrok.io/api/createPdf', {
      method: 'post',
      data: { html },
      responseType: 'json',
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('pdf ', res.data)
        sharePdf(res.data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('err ', error)
      })

    Alert.alert('Ordered Success', 'press ok to save a copy', [
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        onPress: () => {},
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        style: 'cancel',
      },
    ])
    props.resetOrder()
    setOrders([])
  }
```

Node backend to create the pdf

```js
router.post('/createPdf', (req, res) => {

  const {html} = req.body

  pdf.create(html).toBuffer((err, buffer) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', buffer.length)
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
    var pdfBuffer = new Buffer.from(buffer)
    res.send(pdfBuffer)
    console.log('buffer ', pdfBuffer)
  })
  pdf.create(html).toStream((err, pdfStream) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 200
      pdfStream.on('end', () => {
        return res.end()
      })
      pdfStream.pipe(res)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you able to get the pdf response when you try with postman?

Comment: I can get the pdf response, but i don't know how to work with the response with react native frontend.